# Bootstrap DatePicker on Safari / Angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, safari, datepicker

i need some help with the safari browser. I have a angular app which have a function to select on ngOnInit the current week in a datepicken.

It works fine with firefox, brave, chrome and so on.

[image]

but it doesn't work on safari.

[image]

i don't know how to solve it. and the google search doesn't help me anyway. some say that it doesn't work on safari but not how i can solve it.

as already mentioned, i need a datepicker that automatically selects the current week. because i have to save the week number + year ("22/2022") in the database. but i also want to be able to select the next weeks.

ts page

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onDateSelection(this.calendar.getToday());
  }


  getWeekNumber(from: NgbDate) {
    let currentDate = new Date(from.year, from.month, from.day);

    var oneJan = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var numberOfDays = Math.floor(
      (Number(currentDate) - Number(oneJan)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    );

    return Math.ceil((currentDate.getDay() + 1 + numberOfDays) / 7);
  }


  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    let fromDate = new Date(date.year + "-" + date.month + "-" + date.day);

    let time = fromDate.getDay() ? fromDate.getDay() - 1 : 6;
    fromDate = new Date(fromDate.getTime() - time * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    this.fromDate = new NgbDate(
      fromDate.getFullYear(),
      fromDate.getMonth() + 1,
      fromDate.getDate()
    );
    const toDate = new Date(fromDate.getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    this.toDate = new NgbDate(
      toDate.getFullYear(),
      toDate.getMonth() + 1,
      toDate.getDate()
    );

    this.currentDate = `${
      this.fromDate.day < 10 ? "0" + this.fromDate.day : this.fromDate.day
    }.${
      this.fromDate.month < 10 ? "0" + this.fromDate.month : this.fromDate.month
    }. - ${this.toDate.day < 10 ? "0" + this.toDate.day : this.toDate.day}.${
      this.toDate.month < 10 ? "0" + this.toDate.month : this.toDate.month
    }.${this.toDate.year}`;


  }


  isHovered(date: NgbDate) {
    return (
      this.fromDate &&
      !this.toDate &&
      this.hoveredDate &&
      date.after(this.fromDate) &&
      date.before(this.hoveredDate)
    );
  }


  isInside(date: NgbDate) {
    return this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate) && date.before(this.toDate);
  }


  isRange(date: NgbDate) {
    return (
      date.equals(this.fromDate) ||
      (this.toDate && date.equals(this.toDate)) ||
      this.isInside(date) ||
      this.isHovered(date)
    );
  }
```

html page
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had just to modify the new Date() to

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    let fromDate = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

safari has too much date format regex. you have to replace like that. for example

```
  getWeekNumber(from: NgbDate) {
     let currentDate = new Date(from.year.replace(/-/g, "/"), from.month.replace(/-/g, "/"), from.day.replace(/-/g, "/"));
     ...
  }
```